# Packaging a python app with a config file?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I'm writing a Python CLI app and want to package it. I need the app to have a config file that applies to the entire "installation" (i.e. no matter where the user calls my CLI app from, it needs to read this config file).

I want this to be in the package install directory, not just some arbitrary place on the filesystem if I can avoid it. What's the un-messy way to do this?

Comment: To understand your question well: is it a config file just for an _installation_ (you have put that word in quotes), or a config file that should be used at every execution of your app? On which platform?

Comment: Sorry, I mean it is a config file that should be used at every execution of the app. On Linux (Debian/Ubuntu). I mostly wanted to distinguish between a sort of system-wide config file (what I want) and a per-user config file.

Comment: Really good question. Just to be sure, the config is supposed to be editable, right?

Comment: I've done something similar in two different ways. Option 1 is to pass in the path to the config.ini file. Another is to read in the default and be able to use CLI arguments to override individual values.

Comment: I usually have 4 levels of configs in my apps. 1) The defaults, which is an .ini file that is part of the package, 2) the user.ini, (or site.ini, in this case), which is initialized with the default.ini and can then be altered by users, 3) env-vars that follow the pattern `MY_CLI_APP_BASIC_FOO=1`, to mimic the setting in my post, and 4) options when calling the app, like `$ my-cli-app --basic-foo 1 sub-command`

Comment: Not that more ways to provide configuration is necessarily better, but those are the standards I found in other tools, and by now I just have templates that I use for any new app.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to give a "that's not what you want to do"-answer, but I would strongly advice against bundling an editable config file into your package. The reasons being:

- Any serious os has well-defined standards where user- or system-level configs should go. Putting your app's config there as well is not messy at all.
- Python packages (read, `.wheel` files) don't need to be unzipped in order to be runnable, so any os that supports python may chose not to do so on install. If you want to edit a config that is in there, you need to unzip the package first, which is a bit inconvenient.
- For the same reason, the config can't be found with search-tools. So good luck to your users if they ever forget where it was.
- Last and least importantly, there is an assumption that an executable is static. In other languages where the code is compiled there is no way for it not to be, but for interpreted languages I'd deem it good style to follow suit.

But the best argument for following standards is usually that you get to use well-written tools that support said standard, in this case [`appdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/). It can (among other things) find the common config-directory for you, so using it is as simple as this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from appdirs import site_config_dir
from configparser import ConfigParser


def load_config():
    # .ini is easiest to work with, but .toml is probably better in the long run
    cfg_loc = Path(site_config_dir(appname="my_cli_app", appauthor="K4KFH")) / "config.ini"
    # that's it, that was the magic. the rest of the code here is just for illustration

    if not cfg_loc.exists():
        cfg_loc.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        with open(config_loc) as f:
            f.write(
                "[basic]\n"
                "foo = 1\n"
            )
        print(f"Initialized new default config at {config_loc}.")

    cfg = ConfigParser()
    cfg.read(cfg_loc)
    return cfg
```

Which, on Windows, will get you this:

```py
>>> cfg = load_config()
Initialized new default config at C:\ProgramData\K4KFH\my_cli_app\config.ini.
>>> cfg["basic"]["foo"]
1
```

And on debian buster this:

```py
>>> cfg = load_config()
Initialized new default config at /etc/xdg/my_cli_app/config.ini.
>>> cfg["basic"]["foo"]
1
```

Comment: But `cfg_loc` is not defined. `cfg_dir` is defined, which is confusing since it is a file and not a directory. Perhaps pass in `cfg_dir` into `load_config` so you can work with a per-user config.

Comment: @astrochun a typo from an earlier version, my bad.